# Превратить строку типа '2021.186' в дату типа '06.07'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Суть в том, что у меня используется первый вариант '2021.186' (где 186 - количество дней, пройденное в году) для работы с **sqlite3**, а для return *(чтобы все было красиво)* нужно иметь что-то похожее на 2 вариант '06.07'

Comment: Вообще, в sqlite есть специальные типы данных - DATE и DATETIME, лучше в них хранить, а не в строках.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью стандартного модуля [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s = '2021.186'
year, days = map(int, s.split('.'))
date = datetime(year=year, month=1, day=1) + timedelta(days=days)
print(f"{date:%d.%m.%Y}")
```

Вывод: 06.07.2021

Answer (score 2):

Можно и в одну строку с парсингом через `strptime`, потом `timedelta` (т.к. нам нужно смещение в один день) и форматируем дату в строку.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_str = '2021.186'

print((datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y.%j") + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d.%m"))  
# 06.07
```